# Servlet forward() from POST to GET

Tags: servlets, forwarding, http-method

I'm using a simple servlet that receives a POST request and forwards it to another servlet that expects a GET request.

I'm aware as original HtppServletRequest is having POST as it's **method**, thus it's failing to forward. Also, the **HtppServletRequest** method property doesn't have a setter method, only way out i can see is to create a new request object with the method as **GET** and set the remaining contents same as the original request.

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: by request, are you talking about the inputs?

Comment: By POST and GET request i mean, HTTP calls with verb as POST or GET.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by fixing the servlet? It's a problem of forwarding request from servletA to servletB, where the original request was made to servletA (POST request) and we need to forward to servletB(handles only GET request)